# MCP2515 with CSTCE16M0V53

Tags: microcontroller, can, resonance

I need a 16MHZ resonator for my MCP2515. Can I run it with a CSTCE16M0V53-R0 or would that not be sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based [MCP2515 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21801G.pdf), it stated on page 43:

> The bit timing requirements allow ceramic resonators
>   to be used in applications with transmission rates of up
>   to 125 kbit/sec as a rule of thumb. For the full bus
>   speed range of the CAN protocol, a quartz oscillator is
>   required. A maximum node-to-node oscillator variation
>   of 1.7% is allowed.

So if your application use transmission rates 125 kbit/sec or lower, it may use ceramic resonators, example CSTCE16M0V53-R0 (0.5% accuracy). For higher rate, use crystal. Quartz crystals are more accurate and temperature stable than ceramic resonators. You may use 16 Mhz crystal resonator from [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/Search/Refine.aspx?Keyword=crystal+resonator+16Mhz) or [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/crystals-and-oscillators/crystals/852333?k=crystal%2016Mhz)